# Getting org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException when deploying Spring Boot app to Google App Engine

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my `Spring Boot 3` app to `Google App Engine` but I'm getting the error     `org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]`.
I see the exceptions which occurred on the [dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine):
[image]

Is the `Google App Engine` `Ubuntu 22` VM missing the `mysql` driver or so?

Locally and in my IDE `IntelliJ IDEA`, the REST API works fine and does not run into this error.

My `Google App Engine` `app.yaml` config looks as follows:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "17" # When not specified, uses the latest version available
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,mysql"
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Another strange thing is that defining my database connection in an `application-mysql.properties` file did not pick up the connection properties (incorrect) but defining it in an `application.properties` file made `Google App Engine` pick up the properties despite the fact that `Spring Boot` said that the profiles `gcp` and `mysql` are active (correct).

My deployment command is: `mvn clean package appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp -DskipTests`

How do I successfully connect to my `Google Cloud Engine` `mysql` instance? My database config is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<database_name>?cloudSqlInstance=<instance_connection_name>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<username>&password=<password>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

(Of course with placeholders replaced by the correct values)

Using the `Cloud Shell` I was able to connect to the `mysql` database instance just fine and perform arbitrary operations.

EDIT:
My `pom.xml` contains the `mysql` dependency as follows:

```
<!-- MySQL database support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The error says it cannot find the driver. Do you have the mysql dependency in your pom.xml or gradle file? Please provide it (the pom og gradle file). Are you building native maybe?

Comment: @grekier: Yes, my `pom.xml` contains the `mysql` dependency, it works locally. I'm not building native, just regular Java with `maven`. I couldn't get `GraalVM` native compilation to work yet with `Spring Boot`, either (I'm using `Windows`).

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#intro), double quotes (`" "`) should not be included. It should be `operating_system: ubuntu22
  runtime_version: 17`